# How to grep numbers from a log file matched with a pattern

Tags: text-processing

I want to extract some information from the log file which reads:

```
...
Running ep. 0
...
...
Initial position for this ep is 7.338690864048985,28.51815509409351,11.795143979909135
...
...
...
Running ep. 1
...
...
Initial position for this ep is 10.599326804010953,7.514871863851674,14.843070346933654
...
...
```

Now I have a bash code that can extract some data from it as

```
cat screen2.dat|grep -oP 'Running ep. \K([0-9]+)|(?<=for this ep is )[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?'|paste -d' ' - -
```

but the output is only the number after the "Running ep." and the first number after the "Initial position for this ep is "

```
0 7.338690864048985 
1 10.599326804010953 
.
.
.
```

I am expecting something like

```
0 7.338690864048985 28.51815509409351 11.795143979909135
1 10.599326804010953 7.514871863851674 14.843070346933654
.
.
.
```

Comment: You don't allow for more than a single floating point number, that's why. I wonder why you try to match a floating-point number at all. Don't you always want the rest of that line?  Also, when I use the `grep` command on the data you provided, I don't get the same result; I get a newline character instead of a space between the fields.

Comment: @they I missed one componet in my cat command I posted here. I should be `cat screen2.dat|grep -oP 'Running ep. \K([0-9]+)|(?<=for this ep is )[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?'|paste -d' ' - -` By the way, how can I get the rest of the line after the (?<=for this ep is ) without specifying the floating-point?

Comment: @AomSankaewtong If you have new questions, info, test results or similar to add, or if something's not correct in your question, please don't put them in commentaries. Edit your question instead to add it. This way all relevant, current and correct details are directly available for community members.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are over-specifying the expression. You are only ever matching a single floating-point number after the substring `for this ep is` .  If you want the rest of the line, use something like

```bsh
grep -oP 'Running ep\. \K(.*)|for this ep is \K(.*)' screen2.dat |
paste -d ' ' - -
```

With standard `sed`, you might write

```bsh
sed -n -e 's/^Running ep\. //p' -e 's/.*for this ep is //p' screen2.dat |
paste -d ' ' - -
```

Just chop off (remove by substitute by nothing) the bits of the line that you don't need.

You could also use `awk` in the same way,

```bsh
awk '/^Running ep\. / || /for this ep is / { print $NF }' screen2.dat |
paste -d ' ' - -
```

or, to format it all in one go,

```bsh
awk '/^Running ep\. / { ep = $NF } /for this ep is / { print ep, $NF }' screen2.dat
```

Comment: Got it!!. Thanks for saving my day ><

Answer (score 3):

Your code `[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?` matches a single number with optional digits after the dot. If you want three of those, just say so: `([+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?,?){3}`

But what you really want, you can get with a single `sed` csript:

```
sed -e '/Running ep. /{s///;h;}' -e '/.*for this ep is /!d;s///;H;x;s/[\n,]/ /g' screen2.dat
```

- `/Running ep. /{...}` is to execute everything inside `{}` only for lines that match `Running ep.`
- For these lines `s///` removes the part that did match before and move that lines to the `h`old space
- `/.*for this ep is /!d` no all lines that don't (`!`) match that other pattern can be `d`elected,
- And for the rest `s///` simply removes the pattern again, leaving the rest of the line with all that numbers
- `H` appends this remain to the hold space where we can the ep number
- `x` exchanges buffers, so both parts we collected in the hold space are now in pattern space and
- `s/[\n,]/ /g` replaces the embedded newline and all commas with spaces

Comment: The sed command works like a charm!! Thank you so much

Comment: To replace newlines and commas with spaces, it would be quicker and more portable to use `y/\n,/  /`.

Answer (score 3):

With `pcregrep` and its `M`ultiline mode:

```bsh
$ <input pcregrep -M -o{1..4} --om-separator=' ' \
  '(?sm)^Running ep\. (\d+)$.*?^Initial position for this ep is ([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),((?2)),((?2))$'
0 7.338690864048985 28.51815509409351 11.795143979909135
1 10.599326804010953 7.514871863851674 14.843070346933654
```

Though note that if the `Initial...` is missing for a particular `Running ep...`, the `.*?` will happilly match over another `Running ep...` and you'll end up with the wrong ep number in front of a given set of values.

May be better to do it with `gawk` with something like:

```
<input gawk -v 'FPAT=[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?' '
  /^Running ep/ && NF == 1 {ep = $1; next}
  /^Initial position for this ep is/ && ep != "" && NF == 3 {
    print ep, $1, $2, $3
    ep = "" # omit if there can be more than one "Initial position"
            # per ep.
  }'
```

Where `FPAT` defines fields as the strings that match the regexp (numbers), and we only print a line of output upon *Initial position* lines and if a corresponding *Running ep* line has been seen before.

Answer (score 2):

I propose another solution with the combination of `sed` and `grep`:

```bsh
$ grep '^Running\|Initial' screen2.dat | sed -e 'N;s/\n\|,/ /g' -e 's/[^0-9. ]\+\|^[^0-9]\+//g'
0       7.338690864048985 28.51815509409351 11.795143979909135
1       10.599326804010953 7.514871863851674 14.843070346933654
```

- `grep` will retrieve only the lines that start with 'Running' and 'Initial'.

  ```
   Running ep. 0
   Initial position for this ep is 7.338690864048985,28.51815509409351,11.795143979909135
   Running ep. 1
   Initial position for this ep is  10.599326804010953,7.514871863851674,14.843070346933654
  ```
- `sed -e 'N;s/\n\|,/ /g'` will substitute newlines and commas for a space

  ```
   Running ep. 0 Initial position for this ep is 7.338690864048985 28.51815509409351 11.795143979909135
   Running ep. 1 Initial position for this ep is 10.599326804010953 7.514871863851674 14.843070346933654
  ```
- Finally `'s/[^0-9. ]\+\|^[^0-9]\+//g` will substitute everything that is not a digit, dot or space, or not a digit at the start of the line

  ```
   0       7.338690864048985 28.51815509409351 11.795143979909135
   1       10.599326804010953 7.514871863851674 14.843070346933654
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/Running ep/{ep=$NF} /Initial position/{print ep, $NF}' file
0 7.338690864048985,28.51815509409351,11.795143979909135
1 10.599326804010953,7.514871863851674,14.843070346933654
```

and if you really want to replace those commas with blanks then:

```
$ awk '/Running ep/{ep=$NF} /Initial position/{gsub(/,/," ",$NF); print ep, $NF}' file
0 7.338690864048985 28.51815509409351 11.795143979909135
1 10.599326804010953 7.514871863851674 14.843070346933654
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -ne 'state @a; @a.push($<ind> || $<val> // next) if \
    m/^^"Running ep. " $<ind>=[\d+] $$/fff/^^"Initial position for this ep is " $<val>=[.+] $$/; \
    END .put for @a.rotor(2);'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
Running ep. 0
...IMPORTANT...
Initial position for this ep is 7.338690864048985,28.51815509409351,11.795143979909135
...DISCARD...
...DISCARD...
...DISCARD...
Running ep. 1
...IMPORTANT...
Initial position for this ep is 10.599326804010953,7.514871863851674,14.843070346933654
...DISCARD...
```

Sample Output:

```
0 7.338690864048985,28.51815509409351,11.795143979909135
1 10.599326804010953,7.514871863851674,14.843070346933654
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages.

Briefly, Raku's `fff` (flip-flop) operator is used--but only to return two named-captures. In general, Raku's `fff` flip-flop operator captures text between two "sentinel" regexes (including the regex matches, if desired). A skeleton version of `fff` code is `.say if m/OPEN/ fff m/CLOSE/;`. This means that when the Sample Input is evaluated, the sections with unimportant, `...DISCARD...` lines are, well, discarded.

The code above reads input `-ne` linewise, which is memory-efficient. It uses `$<ind>` (index) and `$<val>` (value) named captures. The code also uses `||` short-circuiting `OR` as well as Raku's `//` "defined-OR" operator, which skips to the `next` element if the LHS is undefined (i.e. `Nil`).

A nice spin is quickly changing the code from only returning the captures (above), to returning the paired captures *with intervening lines*. Simply drop the "named-regex" code and use `(.put if .chars)` instead. [Or run the highly simplified code below]:

```
raku -ne '.say if m/^Running/ fff m/^Initial/;'
```

Sample Output (capturing intervening text):

```
Running ep. 0
...IMPORTANT...
Initial position for this ep is 7.338690864048985,28.51815509409351,11.795143979909135
Running ep. 1
...IMPORTANT...
Initial position for this ep is 10.599326804010953,7.514871863851674,14.843070346933654
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://raku.org